# HTML: putting <div> inside <col>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, col

I have a table and I am trying to get a modal to (visually) appear above a column of the table when I click on it.

So far, the best way I have found to "find" the columns of the table is to use the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags. In order to achieve what I want, I need to be able to put a `<div>` inside the column. Naively putting the `<div>` below the `<col>` tag doesn't work, nor does trying to use the `<col>` itself as the container.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Or alternatively, is there a better way to wrap a column in the table with a `<div>`?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say *above*? Visually in the rendered document? Or above the code?

Comment: Visually in the rendered document

Comment: Why do you need to wrap them with `div`s? Styling?

Comment: I need some sort of container for the modal, does not need to be necessarily a  `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to wrap a column in an element.

`<col />` elements exist solely to describe the presentation of a column (and that in a limited way).

The markup structure of a table is purely based on rows. This is a limitation on the nature of HTML as a hierarchal language.

---

If your goal is to add the element so you can use it with a descendant combinator to select all the cells with CSS/JS, then consider `:nth-child` instead.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I'll look into `:nth-child`